# Restricting the Google API key such that the key is available throughout the application

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular8

I am using the Google Places as well as Distance Matrix API in my Angular 8 application.

I have also tried to restrict the key on the Google cloud platform by entering the application URL (http://ipaddress:portno).

I then added the Google API link along with the key in the script tag in index.html page.

My application structure is as under:

src > app > multiple modules under app folder (Login, Location etc)

Under one such module say LocationModule, I have created a google-places.directive. I am then using this directive in my LocationComponent.html.

It all works fine until I do not restrict the key.

When I restrict my key by placing the application URL (http://ipaddress:portno), I get the following error:

The URL http://ipaddress:portno/login is not authorised.
Similarly, when i login and go to the LocationComponent, it says "The URL http://ipaddress:portno/location is not authorised.

Where exactly should I place the Google API link in my application, so as to use it across all components and not having to add URLs of each module of my application in the Google Restrict Key URL list.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the same in `index.html` of yours.

Inside the body tag try using the link with script tags like

```
<script src=”http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did move the Script tag inside the body tag in Index.html. However, I am still facing the same issue. It ssays http://ip:port/login not authorised. The http://ip:port URL is authorised though in the key restrictions.

Comment: Can you do ng serve using this ng serve --host 0.0.0.0

You can go to system preferences > network > wifi, there you can check ip in case of mac